# TypeError: string.padStart is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The below code is a node JS function. I Was trying to run it from Postman and I am getting "TypeError: cartItem.findOne() is not a function".

later I tried to run other WORKING function and got the same error saying " TypeError: item.padStart' is not a function. I am getting the same error for all the functions.

Does it has something to do with the versions?

I tried updating all the node dependencies, deleted and pulled the working code and still getting the same error.

Downloaded a different ID and executed from there, also getting the same error.

Deleted and pulled the code from GIT master and still getting the same error.

Executed using VScode and JetBrains.

```
const cartItem = require('../models/Cart');

const addItemToCart = (context,req) =>{
    let itemInfo = JSON.parse(req.body);

            cartItem.findOne({
                NID: req.headers.NID
            })
        }
```

The below line is from different function:

```
item.padStart(13, "0");
```

Please let me know, if you need further information. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Well what is `item`?

Comment: item is a string variable.

Comment: @rviDesai obviously not, or it would have  padStart method. Unless you're using a *very* old version of node.js.

Comment: I see my machine has 10.16.0 node installed on it. In some of my projects we are using 6.x.x, do you think that it has to do with anything?

Comment: Node 6 passed it's end-of-life date, so you should definitely not used it these days. https://github.com/nodejs/Release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually installed the Azure core function tools  before. Later I deleted and downloaded as VS code suggested, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`item` is probably a number since you're adding zeroes on to the end of it - convert it to a string first. Also remember to reassign the value back to `item`:

```
item = String(item).padStart(13, "0");
```

Comment: Now I am getting the same TypeError at a different place   ```if (Object.values(pluMap).indexOf(scan_code) > -1)```      ```TypeError: Object.values is not a function```

Comment: What is your node environment? `Object.values` is available from 7, or 6.5 with the `--harmony` flag.